# Driving a LED Matrix with a N-channel MOSFET (2N3819) using an AVR

Tags: avr, led, switches, mosfet, matrix

I am trying to wire up a LED matrix using a FET transistor as a switch.

The AVR will be connected to the gate. To turn the LEDs on I have drive the pin connected to the transistor gate low, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2N3819 is an RF 'N' channel depletion mode JFET and is not really suitable for LED switching. Depletion mode means that the gate needs to be driven abut 7 volts *more negative* than the source to turn it off, and driven to the source voltage *but no higher* to turn it on. The maximum drain current is probably not high enough for your needs either.

Look for an N channel enhacement mode MOSFET instead.

Comment: Yeah I think that's what my mate was recommending. Trouble is he tried to explain but me no comprehendo. So with the N channel MOSFET it's turn it low to switch on right?

Comment: No. MOSFETS are enhancement mode so the gate is high to switch on.

Comment: Just for the record: most normal (called "power") MOSFETs are enhancement mode (you will have a hard time finding a depletion mode power MOSFET). With enhancement mode the N-channel type expects high voltage to switch on and P-channel type needs low voltage (negative with respect to the source pin which you commonly connect to you power supply -- a high-side switch).

Answer (score 1):

The 2N3819 is a poor choice because of its limited current-handling capability and because it needs a negative voltage on the gate to turn it off. A BJT would be more suitable.

Comment: It's an N channel Fet. 2N3819. http://www.ee.buffalo.edu/courses/elab/2N3819.pdf

Comment: Dammit! you posted your edits just as I posted my answer :)

Comment: Sorry about that! He originally just said that he was using a FET, type unspecified.